# como se asigna un valor a variable dinamica?

Tags: javascript

quería saber de que manera puedo asignar un valor a varias variables en un loop. este es mi codigo hasta ahora:

```
for (var i = 0; i < base; i++) {
    this['number' + i] = 0;
    eval('number'+i)=i;
```

lo que busco es que cada ciclo del loop se cree una variable*N* y que luego se le asigne el valor *N* correspondiente, quedando asi:

number0=0;

number1=1;

etc.

Comment: En este caso no sería mejor crear un arreglo? `number[i] = i;`

Comment: en ese caso devuelve Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined

Comment: declaraste la variable fuera del loop? `var number = [];`

Comment: en ese caso, aunque me devuelve la cantidad correcta de variables, todas tienen el valor asignado en la linea 

this['number' + i] = 0;

por lo tanto, la linea 

number[i] = i; 

no tiene ningún efecto.

Comment: ¿ Es que tienes que usar `eval` **obligatoriamente** ? Si `this['number' + i]` te funciona, ¿ porqué no haces directamente `this['number' + i] = i;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión de `eval` ocupa la asignación dentro del mismo, este código debería ser lo que buscas a menos que no tenga en claro la pregunta:

```
for (var i = 0; i < base; i++) {
    this['number' + i] = 0;
    eval('number'+ i +'='+ i);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, esto es lo que buscaba